# Shortcode inside other shortcode Wordpress ACF

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

how to use this function correctly:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[product id="<?php the_field('wyrozniony_produkt_id')?>"]'); ?>
```

I need write inside this in place 3931

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[product id="3931"]'); ?>
```

This shortcode  (textfield from ACF)

```
<?php the_field('wyrozniony_produkt_id')?>
```

Anyone have idea how to make this?

Comment: did you try `<?php echo do_shortcode('[product id="'.get_field("wyrozniony_produkt_id").'"]'); ?>`

Comment: that's work perfect, very thank you for your advice, cheers

Answer (score 0):

your syntax seems to be wrong
please check the updated code of yours

```
<?php 
$product_id = get_field('wyrozniony_produkt_id');
echo do_shortcode('[product id="'.$product_id.'"]');
?>
```